# 14.04 AR9k wireless driver reclaim

Tags: 14.04, wireless, atheros

*I'm assuming that at some point I may have mistakenly assigned the wrong driver to my wireless card while attempting to boost signal strength. Is there any commands that would allow me to reclaim my wifi card and set the correct drives?*

It took a minute to find it, but I think this is the command that did it.

```
sudo apt-get install firmwire-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
```

which did not install, or this one,

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

In the windows driver installer the files were `netathr.inf` and `netathrx.inf`. The program marked them with an error of which I can't remember.

I have re-installed bcmwl-kernel-source and nothing. I don't even know if it is related to my problem.

My card is

```
Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01).
```

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in which I have just upgraded to in hopes that it would fix this same problem I experienced in 12.04 LTS.

I'm currently running wifi from a usb controller, but I need the internal card to work because this wifi usb controller is not mine, nor is it small. It is very large for what it is and I would much rather have my laptop work like it is supposed to.

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0100000-f010ffff
```

In case more info is needed.

`rfkill list all`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`nmcli nm`

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled
```

`iwconfig` without usb controller

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

I have entered the following code with no result.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree wicd wicd-gtk wicd-daemon wicd-cli wicd-curses
```

Comment: you installed what driver from where?  How did you install the driver?

Comment: "some point I have mistakenly assigned the wrong driver to my wireless card " ... your words.  How did you assign the wrong driver?  Add the details to your question.  What windows driver did you install from the software center?  What broadcomm package did you install?

Comment: Hey - no worries.  +1 for a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked all over and I found my answer.

The answer was at the bottom of [this page on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2190930.html) from "praseodym"

> Deactivate the hardware encryption of the driver:
>
> ```
> echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
> sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
> sudo modprobe -v ath9k
> ```

I ran `sudo lshw -C network` and found that the "UNCLAIMED" marking next to my wifi card was gone and I could connect again. Thank you praseodym, wherever you are.