# Network unclaimed shown for network controller

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, lenovo

I am facing difficulties connecting to wifi on my Lenovo Flex 3 1480 laptop on Ubuntu 14.04. It works fine on Windows. I am attaching wireless-info.txt that I got from :
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 25 Jan 2016 13:52 MST -0700
Booted last: 25 Jan 2016 13:47 MST -0700
Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 11:24:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3835]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e360 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:2083 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0670 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c535 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211              638976  0 
cfg80211              532480  1 mac80211
compat                 28672  2 cfg80211,mac80211
ideapad_laptop         24576  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    20480  0 

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:10.218.104.240  Bcast:10.218.111.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8295 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1212 errors:0 dropped:25 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1871640 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:156822 (156.8 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.218.104.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.218.104.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search cidse.dhcp.asu.edu

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1017     1  0 13:47 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.218.104.240
    Prefix:          21 (255.255.248.0)
    Gateway:         10.218.104.1

    DNS:             129.219.17.200
    DNS:             129.219.17.5
    DNS:             129.219.13.81

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=asu
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Phoenix (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/updates/dkms/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
version:        backported from  () using backports 
srcversion:     BEF453E7AC487F911F8EDBF
depends:        cfg80211,compat
vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/updates/dkms/cfg80211.ko
version:        backported from  () using backports 
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     F6775E4370E54D5795E4BE2
depends:        compat
vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf]
options ath10k_core skip_otp=y

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath10k-dkms.conf]
options ath10k_core skip_otp=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf]
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   13.723430] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   13.725722] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_new_nm
[   13.725723] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err -22)
[   13.725736] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_register
[   13.725737] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -22)
[   13.725783] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_unregister
[   13.725784] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err -22)
[   13.725798] wl: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_channel
[   13.725799] wl: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_channel (err -22)
[   13.725832] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_free
[   13.725833] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err -22)
[   14.123327] ath: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory
[   14.123331] ath: Unknown symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory (err -22)
[   14.123338] ath: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_channel
[   14.123339] ath: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_channel (err -22)
[   14.123346] ath: disagrees about version of symbol freq_reg_info
[   14.123347] ath: Unknown symbol freq_reg_info (err -22)
[   21.831480] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[   21.831527] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   26.392468] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
[   26.392477] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   51.394064] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
[  120.582163] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up

########## wireless info END ############
```

Please indicate why I am getting "network unclaimed". I have tried following the following, without any positive results. Ethernet works fine.

https://askubuntu.com/a/708103/497674
https://askubuntu.com/a/481221/497674

Edit 1: Adding dkms status

```
root@ankita-Flex-3-1480:/home/ankita# dkms status
backath10k, 2.0, 3.13.0-77-generic, x86_64: installed
backath10k, 2.0, 3.19.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
backath10k, 2.0, 3.19.0-49-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 3.13.0-77-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 3.19.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 3.19.0-49-generic, x86_64: installed
root@ankita-Flex-3-1480:/home/ankita# sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package broadcom-sta-common
E: Unable to locate package broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit to add result for `dkms status`

Comment: And uninstall the broadcom module `sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-dkms`

Comment: I have removed bcm module. Still no success with wireless network.

Comment: `sudo dkms remove backath10k/2.0 --all`  Reboot, then see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/708103/300665)

Comment: Hi thank you the command above worked. I didn't have to do the installation again. Not sure how removing backath10k alone solved the problem

Comment: I am not sure how it could have affected your wifi but I did make the backath10k dkms for the QCA6164, 168c:0041 wifi but it should have affected only the QCA6174 as both chipsets look to the same directory for firmware

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you remove the incorrect and probably conflicting driver. At the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and then run:

```
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath
```

Post the result and, depending on the outcome, I will further edit my answer to propose a solution.

The first link you gave is the correct method; however, it appears that something has gone wrong with the compile process. Let's see if we can fix it:

```
cd backports-20151120
make clean
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

Any improvement? If not, reboot and post again:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

Comment: This is what I get after running the second command:
root@ankita-Flex-3-1480:/home/ankita# sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath10k_pci': Invalid argument

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved using the comments posted by Jeremy31 in the question.

Run:

```
sudo dkms remove backath10k/2.0 --all
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This one solved my problem

```
sudo aptitude install linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic
```

- You might want to check which is the latest version when you install it. (try typing until "image-extra-" and use the auto-complete with tab to find the latest)
- my hardware: intel wifi "Centrino Ultimate-N 6300" on lenovo x201

Answer (score 0):

I've uploaded the installed OS using below `Settings-> About This Computer -> Details -> Overview -> Install Update`

This option will do necessary updates automatically and resolve all the issue

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJOys.png]